# Xcode is not supported on this architecture

Tags: xcode5

I am trying to download Xcode on my MacBook but once it is downloaded I receive the message " you can't open the application "Xcode " because it is not supported on this architecture. My MacBook is OS X version 10.5.8 and I have tried many Xcode from the latest to Xcode 5.1.1 with no result.

Comment: Mac OS X 10.5.8 is quite old, and hence you’ll need a correspondingly old version of Xcode. I’m running Xcode 3.2.5, and it requires at least Mac OS X 10.6.4, so you’ll need to go back even further.

Comment: Latest release of OSX is 10.10 (10.11 in about 7 days).

Comment: The last one that was available to run on 10.5. was Xcode 3.1.3 https://developer.apple.com/downloads/